# MS-SQL - ODBC - INSERT fails when applied on an "Always Encrypted" VARCHAR(MAX) column

Tags: sql-server, odbc

### Heading ##MS-SQL - ODBC - INSERT fails when applied on an "Always Encrypted" VARCHAR(MAX) column

The following program attempts to load a text file into a VARCHAR(max) column - using ODBC.
The VARCHAR(MAX) column is encrypted - using 'Always Encrypted' feature.

```
create table clobTable
(
id integer identity(1,1) primary key not null,
--clobCol varchar(max)
clobCol [varchar](max) COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN2 ENCRYPTED WITH (COLUMN_ENCRYPTION_KEY = [CEK1], ENCRYPTION_TYPE = Deterministic, ALGORITHM = 'AEAD_AES_256_CBC_HMAC_SHA_256') NULL
);
```

The INSERT statement fails upon execution while informing the following error message:

```
Native error = 206
Message text = [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Operand type clash: varchar(max) encrypted with (encryption_type = 'DETERMINISTIC', encryption_algorithm_name = 'AEAD_AES_256_CBC_HMAC_SHA_256', column_encryption_key_name = 'CEK1', column_encryption_key_database_name = 'AEdemo') collation_name = 'Compatibility_136_8200_0' is incompatible with varchar(max) encrypted with (encryption_type = 'DETERMINISTIC', encryption_algorithm_name = 'AEAD_AES_256_CBC_HMAC_SHA_256', column_encryption_key_name = 'CEK1',
SQLState     = 37000
Native error = 8180
Message text = [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Statement(s) could not be prepared.
```

Notes:

1. When applying this program on a table in which VARCHAR(MAX) column
   is not encrypted - it works perfectly fine.
2. Following is issued via MS-SQL server management studio and it works fine:

```
declare @v varchar(max) = '111111111111111111222222222222222222222223333333333333333333333334444444444444444'
insert into clobTable (clobCol) values (@v)
```

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <sql.h>
#include <sqlext.h>
#include <sqltypes.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/*

MS-SQL - ODBC - INSERT fails when applied on an "Always Encrypted" VARCHAR(MAX) column

The following program attempts to load a text file into a VARCHAR(max) column - using ODBC.
The VARCHAR(MAX) column is encrypted - using 'Always Encrypted' feature.

create table clobTable
(
id integer identity(1,1) primary key not null,
--clobCol varchar(max)
clobCol [varchar](max) COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN2 ENCRYPTED WITH (COLUMN_ENCRYPTION_KEY = [CEK1], ENCRYPTION_TYPE = Deterministic, ALGORITHM = 'AEAD_AES_256_CBC_HMAC_SHA_256') NULL
);

The INSERT statement fails upon execution while informing the following error message:

SQLState     = 22005
Native error = 206
Message text = [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Operand type clash: varchar(max) encrypted with (encryption_type = 'DETERMINISTIC', encryption_algorithm_name = 'AEAD_AES_256_CBC_HMAC_SHA_256', column_encryption_key_name = 'CEK1', column_encryption_key_database_name = 'AEdemo') collation_name = 'Compatibility_136_8200_0' is incompatible with varchar(max) encrypted with (encryption_type = 'DETERMINISTIC', encryption_algorithm_name = 'AEAD_AES_256_CBC_HMAC_SHA_256', column_encryption_key_name = 'CEK1',
SQLState     = 37000
Native error = 8180
Message text = [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Statement(s) could not be prepared.

Notes:
1. When applying this program on a table in which VARCHAR(MAX) column is not encrypted - it works perfectly fine.
2. Following is issued via MS-SQL server management studio and it works fine:

declare @v varchar(max) = '111111111111111111222222222222222222222223333333333333333333333334444444444444444'
insert into clobTable (clobCol) values (@v)


*/

#define __CON_STR__  "DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};Server=sql16-w16.qa.int\\mssqlserver2016;Database=AEdemo;UID=xx;PWD=yyyyyyyy;ColumnEncryption=Enabled;"
#define __THE_FILE__     "..\\DevProjects\\mssql-load-file-to-varchar-max\\big-text-file.txt"


static int SQL_OK(SQLRETURN result);
static int printErrors(SQLHENV  envHandle, SQLHDBC  conHandle, SQLHSTMT stmtHandle);
static char * loadedFile(char *pszTheFile);

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    char* pszBigString = NULL;
    const char* pszSQL = "INSERT INTO clobTable (clobCol) VALUES (?)";
    HSTMT hStmt = NULL;
    SQLHENV hEnv = NULL;
    SQLRETURN iError = SQLAllocEnv(&hEnv);
    SQLLEN *        len;

    HDBC hDbc = NULL;
    SQLAllocConnect(hEnv, &hDbc);

    const char* pszConnStr = __CON_STR__;
    UCHAR szConnectOut[SQL_MAX_MESSAGE_LENGTH];
    SWORD iConnectOutLen = 0;
    iError = SQLDriverConnectA(hDbc, NULL, (unsigned char*)pszConnStr,
        SQL_NTS, szConnectOut,
        (SQL_MAX_MESSAGE_LENGTH - 1), &iConnectOutLen,
        SQL_DRIVER_COMPLETE);

    if (!SQL_OK(iError))
    {
        printErrors(SQL_NULL_HENV, hDbc, SQL_NULL_HSTMT);
        exit(-1);
    }

    iError = SQLAllocStmt(hDbc, &hStmt);

    iError = SQLPrepareA(hStmt, (SQLCHAR*)pszSQL, SQL_NTS);
    if (!SQL_OK(iError))
    {
        printErrors(SQL_NULL_HENV, SQL_NULL_HDBC, hStmt);
        exit(-1);
    }

    pszBigString =  loadedFile(__THE_FILE__); // __THE_FILE__;
    len = strlen(pszBigString);

    iError = SQLSetParam(hStmt, 1, SQL_C_CHAR, SQL_VARCHAR, 0, 0, (SQLPOINTER)pszBigString, NULL);

    iError = SQLExecute(hStmt); 
    if (!SQL_OK(iError))
    {
        printErrors(SQL_NULL_HENV, SQL_NULL_HDBC, hStmt);
        exit(-1);
    }

    iError = SQLDisconnect(hDbc);
    if (!SQL_OK(iError))
    {
        printErrors(SQL_NULL_HENV, hDbc, SQL_NULL_HSTMT);
        exit(-4);
    }

    SQLFreeHandle(SQL_HANDLE_STMT, hStmt);
    SQLFreeHandle(SQL_HANDLE_DBC, hDbc);
    SQLFreeHandle(SQL_HANDLE_ENV, hEnv);

}

static /*bool*/ int SQL_OK(SQLRETURN result)
{
    if (result == SQL_SUCCESS || result == SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO)
        return(TRUE);
    else
        return(FALSE);
}


static /*bool*/ int printErrors(SQLHENV  envHandle,
    SQLHDBC  conHandle,
    SQLHSTMT stmtHandle)
{
    SQLRETURN   result;
    SQLWCHAR    sqlState[6];
    SQLINTEGER  nativeError;
    SQLSMALLINT requiredLength;
    SQLWCHAR    messageText[1024 + 1];

    do
    {
        result = SQLError(envHandle,
            conHandle,
            stmtHandle,
            sqlState,
            &nativeError,
            messageText,
            sizeof(messageText),
            &requiredLength);

        if (SQL_OK(result))
        {
            printf("SQLState     = %S\n", sqlState);
            printf("Native error = %d\n", nativeError);
            printf("Message text = %S\n", messageText);
        }
    } while (SQL_OK(result));

    return 0;
}


#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
static char * loadedFile(char *pszTheFile)
{
    struct stat st;
    int statRes;
    _off_t fileSize = 0;
    char *pszFileContents;
    FILE *fp;

    memset(&st, 0, sizeof(st));

    statRes = stat(pszTheFile, &st);
    if (statRes == 0)
        fileSize = st.st_size;
    else
        return NULL;

    pszFileContents = calloc(1, fileSize);

    fp = fopen(pszTheFile, "r");
    fread(pszFileContents, 1, fileSize, fp);
    fclose(fp);

    return pszFileContents;

}
```

Comment: Does the [documentation part about permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/using-always-encrypted-with-the-odbc-driver?view=sql-server-ver15) help?

Comment: Maybe [Configure the max text repl size Server Configuration Option](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/configure-the-max-text-repl-size-server-configuration-option?view=sql-server-ver15), encrypting may increase size.. Try to insert chuncks https://stackoverflow.com/a/59989154/9439330

Answer (score 0):

2020-02-13

The referenced DOC does not help much.
Yet - following that referenced URL "Using Always Encrypted with the ODBC Driver for SQL Server" shows something strange.

The connection string token "ColumnEncryption" value is set to "Enabled".
This would allow both encryption and decryption activities via that ODBC connection.

Now - right after SQLDriverConnect() , following is issued:

```
iError = SQLGetConnectAttr(hDbc, SQL_COPT_SS_COLUMN_ENCRYPTION, (SQLPOINTER)&uIntVal, (SQLINTEGER) sizeof(uIntVal), NULL);
if (!SQL_OK(iError))
{
   printErrors(SQL_NULL_HENV, hDbc, SQL_NULL_HSTMT);
   exit(-1);
}
else
{
  printf("\nConnection attribute SQL_COPT_SS_COLUMN_ENCRYPTION value is : %d", uIntVal);
}
```

This outputs:

```
Connection attribute SQL_COPT_SS_COLUMN_ENCRYPTION value is : 1
```

As per the given DOC - this stands for SQL_CE_RESULTSETONLY  - which allows "decrypt only".

I re-installed the latest ODBC version - in vain. Same error is issued.

What did I miss.

Thanks

Hillel.